# explanation of the following javascript

Tags: javascript

currently stuck on a piece of code as im not sure what the below code does, can someone explain it to me

```
var limits = settings.show != null && settings.show < length ? settings.show : length;
```

Answer (score 4):

That's a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a), same as:

```
var limits;
if (settings.show != null && settings.show < length) {
  limits = settings.show;
} else {
  limits = length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`limits` is set to the result of settings.show if show is not null and smaller than length, otherwise it is set to length.

I assume the part you are stuck on is the x ? y : z. Check out the Mozilla documentation on the conditional operator [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).